# Is this an example of parallelism?

Tags: modifiers, parallelism

1. For dinner we like chicken and stir fried vegetables.

Or do I need to say "*fried* chicken and stir fried vegetables"?

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

> For dinner we like chicken and stir fried vegetables.

I would understand that to be chicken, prepared in just about any way, also served with stir fried vegetables.  If the chicken and vegetables were stir fried together then I suggest you should say it like:

"For dinner we like stir fried chicken and vegetables."

The second example only makes sense if you have fried chicken and stir fried vegetables prepared separately.  In that case you might want to clarify how the chicken is fried such as :

"For dinner we like southern fried chicken and stir fried vegetables."

For reference, "southern fried chicken" is a style of cooking chicken with breading that is popular in the USA especially the southern states.